# How to remove drawer on old Accuride rails

Tags: drawers, removal

I have an old cherry Artec 4 drawer lateral filing cabinet with Accuride file rails.  I cannot figure out how to remove a drawer. There are no black plastic tabs or release mechanism that I can identify. I did insert a screw driver at the end of the rail but didn't feel a catch (did not really apply a lot of pressure).

Is there anyway to release the drawer without removing the rail screws?
I could not locate a model number on the rails - just a Pat pending # that was was teeny tiny to read and the number F 2  [image]

Comment: Pull it out all the way and lift to angle up the drawer??

Comment: That is as far out as the drawer will go.

Comment: If it won't lift off feel the rail some times there is a small metal lever that takes a very slight force, lifting the lever allows the track to slide out.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a couple of decades, but I think this is what I had. You'll notice the front lever that pushes down. Well, that's actually to retain the BB-rail, so the BB's don't fall out...which I did the first time before doing it right...you just put the BB's back in, no big deal.

Anyway, just open the draw enough to get to the front levers and hold them down while you pull the drawer straight out and free of the interior rails. If I recall, it was a bit tough and you feel the BB's scraping their way along.

Reinstallation is the same and you need to release the front levers only when the drawer is almost shut. Then, shut it all of the way and you're back to full smooth operation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might just lift off: https://www.accuride.com/en-us/resources/faqs

Answer (score 0):

Looks similar to what I have, just pull it straight out although it won't easily pull out. When it gets to the point where it's almost all the way out give it a good jerk.

Answer (score 0):

There is a metal piece attached to the drawer with many screws, call this piece A. There is a single screw attaching the slider, piece B, to the drawer. You need to remove the single visible screw holding piece B to the drawer and the drawer and piece A will move forward and lift off when you lift up on the hook-lever on piece A.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).